# how to download file through <embed> tag with a filename?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using embed tag to show pdf file which is downloaded from server. Through embed i can download/print/rotate its contents. The problem is download my pdf file with *FILENAME* through download feature in embed tag.

HTML code:

```html
<embed name="plugin" [src]="selectedDocumentSource | safe" type="application/pdf">
```

- **First approach**

*selectedDocumentSource* is a link to file directly from server. For that i have in response header:
`Content-Disposition: inline; filename="MyDocumentName.pdf"`

The problem of this approach is: this GET is done by browser. Without any extension, and if possible, using typescript, how i could append the authorization header in it?

I'm using angular, but this browser request (and only this one) is not getting intercepted (maybe it runs outside angular or something).

- **Second approach**

I download file instead browser.

```
showDocument(): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        this.selectedDocumentSource = reader.result;
    };
    this.service.getDocument( docId ).subscribe( {
        next: (res: Blob) => reader.readAsDataURL( res )
    } );
}
```

*selectedDocumentSource* is a DataURL. Filename attribute are not documented in this [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) (althought i tried append fileName, filename, name attributes).

When user clicks in download icon (provided by browser), browser prompts where to save "download.pdf" file instead "MyDocumentName.pdf" expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the download attribute on an anchor tag with href to the file you want to download? Have not tried it but something like `<a href="fileSource" download="MyDocumentName.pdf">`

Comment: `<embed>` does not have href attribute like `<a>`. If i had control over download icon maybe this could work

Comment: Correct, sorry I meant to ask if you have tried using anchor instead of <embed>

Comment: I update the `<embed src="#link">` to anchor a `<a id="link">`, but didnt work neihter

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp `<a href="fileSource" download="MyDocumentName.pdf">`

Comment: Yeah, i put a link like yours with an id which i anchor in embed tag. Download has to come from embed tag